# Update.exe doesn't create start menu shortcuts when passing in process-start-args

Tags: electron, squirrel.windows

I'm using [electron-squirrel-startup](https://github.com/mongodb-js/electron-squirrel-startup) to create start menu shortcuts but I need to pass in arguments to the shortcut, right now I'm editing the `index.js` in `node_modules/electron-squirrel-startup` like this:

```
run(['--createShortcut=' + target + ' --process-start-args=showSplash'], app.quit);
```

Although it doesn't create the shortcut anymore.

How can I create the start menu shortcut with arguments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason the child_process `spawn` didn't run the command so I swapped it out for `exec` like this:

```
exec(updateExe + ' ' + args[0], function (err, stdout, stderr) {
    done();
});
```

But I needed to put double quotes around the target as well because it has two words:

```
run(['--createShortcut="' + target + '" --process-start-args=showSplash'], app.quit);
```